# Can some help me out code cleaning/combine

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm busy with a Call of Duty Black Ops 4 with my friends.

Now I have it work but I want to combine the code, because I repeat for every username the whole cURL information. Can someone help me with cleaning my code :)

I have put  between the code which keeps repeating.

Now I have 6 usernames and it means that I repeat every time my cUrl request and a row.

I'm sure that it can work more easier than I did.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user']) && $_GET['user'] != '') {
    $url = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/'.$_GET['user'];
}else{
    $url = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/gurdt';
}

<!--- REPEAT FOR EVERY USERNAME !--->
$userGurdt = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/gurdt';
<!--- END REPEAT FOR EVERY USERNAME !--->
$userRay = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/the_green_ray';
$userRamon = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/hilhorst95';
$userMark = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/r6dutchmennl';
$userLeon = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/theaxeman777';
$userDan = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/fscdan';

<!--- REPEAT FOR EVERY USERNAME !--->
// Gurdt
$chGurdt = curl_init($userGurdt);
curl_setopt($chGurdt, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($chGurdt, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseGurdt = curl_exec($chGurdt);

if(curl_errno($chGurdt)){
    //If an error occurred, throw an Exception.
    throw new Exception(curl_error($chGurdt));
}

$outputGurdt = json_decode($responseGurdt);

$usernameGurdt = $outputGurdt->data->metadata->platformUserHandle;
$levelGurdt = $outputGurdt->data->stats[0]->value;
$levelImgGurdt = $outputGurdt->data->stats[0]->metadata->iconUrl;
$killsGurdt = $outputGurdt->data->stats[2]->value;
$deathsGurdt = $outputGurdt->data->stats[3]->value;
$kdGurdt = $outputGurdt->data->stats[1]->value;
<!--- END REPEAT FOR EVERY USERNAME !--->
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The_Green_Ray
$chRay = curl_init($userRay);
curl_setopt($chRay, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($chRay, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseRay = curl_exec($chRay);

if(curl_errno($chRay)){
    //If an error occurred, throw an Exception.
    throw new Exception(curl_error($chRay));
}

$outputRay = json_decode($responseRay);

$usernameRay = $outputRay->data->metadata->platformUserHandle;
$levelRay = $outputRay->data->stats[0]->value;
$levelImgRay = $outputRay->data->stats[0]->metadata->iconUrl;
$killsRay = $outputRay->data->stats[2]->value;
$deathsRay = $outputRay->data->stats[3]->value;
$kdRay = $outputRay->data->stats[1]->value;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Ramon
$chRamon = curl_init($userRamon);
curl_setopt($chRamon, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($chRamon, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseRamon = curl_exec($chRamon);

if(curl_errno($chRamon)){
    //If an error occured, throw an Exception.
    throw new Exception(curl_error($chRamon));
}

$outputRamon = json_decode($responseRamon);

$usernameRamon = $outputRamon->data->metadata->platformUserHandle;
$levelRamon = $outputRamon->data->stats[0]->value;
$levelImgRamon = $outputRamon->data->stats[0]->metadata->iconUrl;
$killsRamon = $outputRamon->data->stats[2]->value;
$deathsRamon = $outputRamon->data->stats[3]->value;
$kdRamon = $outputRamon->data->stats[1]->value;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Mark
$chMark = curl_init($userMark);
curl_setopt($chMark, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($chMark, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseMark = curl_exec($chMark);

if(curl_errno($chMark)){
    //If an error occured, throw an Exception.
    throw new Exception(curl_error($chMark));
}

$outputMark = json_decode($responseMark);

$usernameMark = $outputMark->data->metadata->platformUserHandle;
$levelMark = $outputMark->data->stats[0]->value;
$levelImgMark = $outputMark->data->stats[0]->metadata->iconUrl;
$killsMark = $outputMark->data->stats[3]->value;
$deathsMark = $outputMark->data->stats[4]->value;
$kdMark = $outputMark->data->stats[2]->value;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Leon
$chLeon = curl_init($userLeon);
curl_setopt($chLeon, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($chLeon, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseLeon = curl_exec($chLeon);

if(curl_errno($chLeon)){
    //If an error occured, throw an Exception.
    throw new Exception(curl_error($chLeon));
}

$outputLeon = json_decode($responseLeon);

$usernameLeon = $outputLeon->data->metadata->platformUserHandle;
$levelLeon = $outputLeon->data->stats[0]->value;
$levelImgLeon = $outputLeon->data->stats[0]->metadata->iconUrl;
$killsLeon = $outputLeon->data->stats[3]->value;
$deathsLeon = $outputLeon->data->stats[4]->value;
$kdLeon = $outputLeon->data->stats[2]->value;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////
// Danny
$chDan = curl_init($userDan);
curl_setopt($chDan, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($chDan, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$responseDan = curl_exec($chDan);

if(curl_errno($chDan)){
    //If an error occured, throw an Exception.
    throw new Exception(curl_error($chDan));
}

$outputDan = json_decode($responseDan);

$usernameDan = $outputDan->data->metadata->platformUserHandle;
$levelDan = $outputDan->data->stats[0]->value;
$levelImgDan = $outputDan->data->stats[0]->metadata->iconUrl;
$killsDan = $outputDan->data->stats[2]->value;
$deathsDan = $outputDan->data->stats[3]->value;
$kdDan = $outputDan->data->stats[1]->value;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PDle/QlgIONtM1aqA2Qemk5gPOE7wFq8+Em+G/hmo5Iq0CCmYZLv3fVRDJ4MMwEA" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>N033 Stats</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-4">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Kills</th>
                <th>Deaths</th>
                <th>K/D</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<!--- REPEAT FOR EVERY USERNAME !--->
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $usernameGurdt;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo '<img src="'.$levelImgGurdt.'" width="40" height="40"/> '.$levelGurdt;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $killsGurdt;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $deathsGurdt;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $kdGurdt;?></td>
            </tr>
<!--- END REPEAT FOR EVERY USERNAME !--->
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $usernameRay;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo '<img src="'.$levelImgRay.'" width="40" height="40"/> '.$levelRay;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $killsRay;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $deathsRay;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $kdRay;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $usernameRamon;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo '<img src="'.$levelImgRamon.'" width="40" height="40"/> '.$levelRamon;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $killsRamon;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $deathsRamon;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $kdRamon;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $usernameMark;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo '<img src="'.$levelImgMark.'" width="40" height="40"/> '.$levelMark;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $killsMark;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $deathsMark;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $kdMark;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $usernameLeon;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo '<img src="'.$levelImgLeon.'" width="40" height="40"/> '.$levelLeon;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $killsLeon;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $deathsLeon;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $kdLeon;?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $usernameDan;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo '<img src="'.$levelImgDan.'" width="40" height="40"/> '.$levelDan;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $killsDan;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $deathsDan;?></td>
                <td valign="middle"><?php echo $kdDan;?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-7aThvCh9TypR7fIc2HV4O/nFMVCBwyIUKL8XCtKE+8xgCgl/PQGuFsvShjr74PBp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OOP and objects should be your friends

Comment: Make an array with the required data for the curl request (username etc.) and use `foreach` to loop through it. Then do the curl request and prepare all the data in an array. Then use `foreach` again in the presentation layer(your HTML at the bottom.) to loop through your prepared result array and print the contents. Your question is a bit offtopic for stackoverflow, you might want to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @B001ᛦ What gain you have by using OOP here? You're just overcomplicating a very simple problem.

Comment: This is just a possible approach to get things done correctly.. if you don't like so keep just moving or flag comment ;) @Xatenev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote your code a little bit by doing what I described in the comment to your question:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$baseUrl = 'https://cod-api.tracker.gg/v1/standard/bo4/profile/2/';
$apiKey = 'XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX';

$users = [
    'gurdt' => [
        'id' => 'gurdt'
    ],
    'ray' => [
        'id' => 'the_green_ray'
    ],
    'ramon' => [
        'id' => 'hilhorst95'
    ],
    'mark' => [
        'id' => 'r6dutchmennl'
    ],
    'leon' => [
        'id' => 'theaxeman777'
    ],
    'dan' => [
        'id' => 'fscdan'
    ]
];

$result = [];

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $url = $baseUrl . $user['id'];
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'TRN-Api-Key: ' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        //If an error occured, throw an Exception.
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }
    $output = json_decode($response, true);
    $result[$user['id']]['username'] = $output['data']['metadata']['platformUserHandle'];
    $result[$user['id']]['level'] = $output['data']['stats'][0]['value'];
    $result[$user['id']]['levelImg'] = $output['data']['stats'][0]['metadata']['iconUrl'];
    $result[$user['id']]['kd'] = $output['data']['stats'][1]['value'];
    $result[$user['id']]['kills'] = $output['data']['stats'][2]['value'];
    $result[$user['id']]['deaths'] = $output['data']['stats'][3]['value'];
}

var_dump($result);

?>
```

EDIT: I have cleaned up the presentation layer a bit too, you don't have to use `<?php echo ?>` all over the place in your HTML, its kinda unreadable. Instead you can use something like heredoc to make it more readable:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-4">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Kills</th>
                <th>Deaths</th>
                <th>K/D</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($result as $r) {
                $username = $r['username'];
                $levelImg = $r['levelImg'];
                $level = $r['level'];
                $kills = $r['kills'];
                $deaths = $r['deaths'];
                $kd = $r['kd'];
                echo <<<EOT
            <tr>
            <td valign="middle">$username</td>
            <td valign="middle"><img src="$levelImg" width="40" height="40"/>$level</td>
            <td valign="middle">$kills</td>
            <td valign="middle">$deaths</td>
            <td valign="middle">$kd</td>
            </tr>
EOT;
            } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```